# Current user name if account name has changed

Tags: c#, .net, windows-authentication

I try to get the name of the current logged in user in c# - not the account name which I could find easily in Environment.UserName. 
I would like to enumerate the folders on MyComputer like explorer does it. How could I do that or is there another way to get the correct name of the user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide what you have done.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here. Could you provide a more illustrative example of what you're trying to do? I especially don't know what "I would like to enumerate the folders on MyComputer like explorer does it" is meant to mean, and how it fits in with the rest of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`  This should return the account of the currently logged in user, and their name.

If that doesn't work after a username change, another method would be to get the current user's SID, then look up a username matching that SID.

```
using System.Security.Principal;
string sid = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Owner.ToString();
return new SecurityIdentifier(sid).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
```

Failing this, take the SID and try and find a matching user either via WMI or via the registry. Instructions on how to do this manually are here: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/registry/ht/find-user-security-identifier.htm

If you can manually confirm that either of those methods return the NEW username, then just implement that in code, with either WMI calls or registry access.

Comment: should catch `SecurityException` with this (possibly return environment name as you are using now as a fall back)

Comment: Your link leads me to the solution:

SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount", string.Format("Domain='{0}'", Environment.MachineName));
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
foreach (ManagementObject mObject in searcher.Get())
{
 Console.WriteLine((string)mObject["Name"] + "\t" + (string)mObject["FullName"]);
}
"FullName" is the property which I've searched for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should post that solution as the answer. Good work on figuring it out

Answer (score 1):

Use it ,

```
string windowLoging = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

or

```
string windowsLogin = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

or

```
string windowsLogin = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");
```

Comment: Let's say we have an account named "Admin" on the machine. If the user changes the name of this user account in control panel i.e. to "Harald" the explorer shows the my documents folder as "Harald" not "Admin". All functions like Identity.name or Environment.UserName get as result "Admin". How can I get the changed user name (i.E: "Harald") of the current logged in user?

Comment: All this code delivers the original user Name - NOT the changed account name. In the sample all this code delivers "Admin" - but I search for a way to get the current name of "Admin" - this is "Harald" how it Explorer displays.

Comment: Can you show me your code , how did you changed your account name ?

Comment: There is no code. I use Control Panel - user management and there "change own user name". This is then the name which is shown on login screen (i.e. "Harald"). The account itself stays at "Admin".

Answer (score 0):

@damienc88
Your link leads me to the solution:

```
    SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount", string.Format("Domain='{0}'", Environment.MachineName)); 
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query); 
    foreach (ManagementObject mObject in searcher.Get()) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine((string)mObject["Name"] + "\t" + (string)mObject["FullName"]); 
    }
```

"FullName" is the property which I've searched for. Thanks a lot. – Harald Pitro